# Doctrine migration runs non-relevant SQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine migration does weirdest thing.

I have migration which is supposed to:

- drop FK on a column
- drop this column
- drop some tables

Because I don't know FK name, I created methods which return and drop FKs by inspecting Doctrine schema object. Instead it seems to do:

- execute my migration
- then re-create just-dropped columns, fk-s and tables after migration has been finished, and outputs these SQLs also

I also note that this is very first migration in this project. If I comment out dropForeignKeys (and therefore schema inspection), then no extra stuff is done.

Why Doctrine does this and how can I prevent it to happen? Doctrine is v2.6.1. Symfony is v3.4.

Migration file:

```
final class Version20180606143534 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $con = $this->connection;

        $this->dropForeignKeys($con, $schema, 'table1', 'table2_id');

        $con->exec('alter table table1 drop column table2_id');

        $con->exec('DROP TABLE table3');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs

    }

    /**
     * Returns foreign keys for a table and optionally column
     * @param Schema $schema
     * @param string $table
     * @param string|null $columnName
     * @return ForeignKeyConstraint[]
     * @throws \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException
     */
    private function getForeignKeys(Schema $schema, $table, $columnName = null)
    {
        $fks = $schema->getTable($table)->getForeignKeys();

        if ($columnName) {
            foreach ($fks as $id => $fk) {
                $columnNames = $fk->getLocalColumns();

                if (!in_array($columnName, $columnNames)) {
                    unset($fks[$id]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $fks;
    }

    private function dropForeignKeys(Connection $con, Schema $schema, $table, $columnName = null)
    {
        $fks = $this->getForeignKeys($schema, $table, $columnName);

//        var_dump(sprintf('..table %s has %s fks', $table, count($fks)));

        foreach ($fks as $fk) {
            $con->exec(sprintf(
                'ALTER TABLE %s DROP FOREIGN KEY %s', $fk->getLocalTableName(), $fk->getName()
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you manually created your doctrine migration or generated it using `doctrine:migrations:diff`? If you're creating it manually doctrine will usually make your SQL match your model, could be that you've not changed the model thus it's overriding your changes

Comment: I dont think it matters - migration is just simple class which executes commands inside `up()`. And there are no other commands besides these 3. Or?

Comment: There are more commands besides these three (see the api reference for more info https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/migrations/1.7/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/AbstractMigration.html#method_postUp). The difference between automatic and manual matters as doctrine may be interpreting your commands different than expected and it may be just easier (and better) to change the model and automatically generate a migration then modify it from there.